# Serializing and deseriazling Objects in JSON

Tags: java, android, json, serialization

Let's say

```
Class ClassA {
    String someString;
    int someInt;
}
```

I want to serialize this object into a JSON string e.g:

```
{"someString" : "hello", "someInt" : 2}
```

and I also want to convert this back into an object of `ClassA`.

I have looked into the GSON library but is there a way I can use reflection or something to automatically detect class fields and convert them into beans?

Comment: Sure, but why not use a library that's already been tested and refined?

Comment: Dave : any library that you would recommend. My google search is getting poorer these days :)

Comment: In GSON, we have to annotate fields to let it know what keys to use for a particular field. I would like to automate this feature without have to annotate each field.

Comment: Not according to its [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is a pretty great JSON processing library.  (No hate against GSON, but in my experience Jackson has been more featureful, and the lead dev is very good about addressing bugs / feature requests)

Comment: seems to be well documented. anyway will look into both of these. thanks